# Select <tag> <and everything inside a /> </tag> in XML

Tags: xml, regex, notepad++

I want to select `<tag>` and all the tags inside it if there are some.

My XML:

```
<item>
    <tag></tag>
    <tag>
        <item>
            <anothertag></anothertag>
        </item>
    </tag>
</item>
```

I'm not very familiar with regex so here is what I've tried:

- `(<tag>)([\\s\\S]*?)(</tag>)`
- `[\t ]*<tag>.*</tag>`

And these regexes only selected empty `<tag></tag>` tags.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, see @Jerry's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(<tag>)([\\s\\S]*?)(</tag>)
```

Backslashes should not be double escaped in Notepad++:

```
<tag>[\s\S]*?</tag>
```

And you don't need to capture the tags nor the `[\s\S]*?`. Unless you're doing some replace you didn't mention.